# How do I pass an env/build arg from my docker-compose script to a Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables, docker-entrypoint

I want to pass an env/build var to my Dockerfile for use in its entryxoint and thought I could do it from the docker-compose file like so

```
  web:
    restart: "no"
    build:
      context: ../my-project
      args:
        CURRENT_ENV: "development"
```

In my Dockerfile, I have this defined

```
ARG CURRENT_ENV
ENTRYPOINT /bin/sh -c "rm -f /app/tmp/pids/*.pid && [[ $CURRENT_ENV = 'dev' ]] && /usr/local/rbenv/versions/`cat .ruby-version`/gemsets/my-project/bin/foreman start -f Procfile || /usr/local/rbenv/versions/`cat .ruby-version`/gemsets/my-project/bin/foreman start -f Procfile.hot; tail -f /dev/null"
```

However when I start my containers using “docker-compose up”, it doesn’t appear the entry point is picking up the variable as it has a empty string before the “= ‘dev’” section …

```
myco-deploy-web-1    | /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `rm -f /app/tmp/pids/*.pid && [[  = 'dev' ]] && /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.4.5/gemsets/my-project/bin/foreman start -f Procfile || /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.4.5/gemsets/my-project/bin/foreman start -f Procfile.hot; tail -f /dev/null'
```

What’s the proper way to pass the build arg/env var to my ENTRYPOINT command?

Comment: (Consider writing this as a shell script rather than a complex inline command, and at the Compose level overriding the container's `command:` rather than trying to build a special dev-only image.)

Answer (score 0):

The ENTRYPOINT needs the variable to be an environment variable rather than a build arg.

You can do this

```
ARG CURRENT_ENV
ENV CURRENT_ENV $CURRENT_ENV
ENTRYPOINT /bin/sh -c "rm -f /app/tmp/pids/*.pid && [[ $CURRENT_ENV = 'dev' ]] && /usr/local/rbenv/versions/`cat .ruby-version`/gemsets/my-project/bin/foreman start -f Procfile || /usr/local/rbenv/versions/`cat .ruby-version`/gemsets/my-project/bin/foreman start -f Procfile.hot; tail -f /dev/null"
```

and it should work